# Can not get the help or documentation of eclipse while typing

Tags: java, eclipse

I work on Eclipse Luna on my windows 7, which I downloaded from their site in the usual way.
(Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1))

While typing a new existing class or method for example, I can not see the documentation,
I just see `arg0`, `arg1` and so on, but no online help with detailed information for every parameter. I know it's possible because I saw it in other places where Eclipse is installed.

How can I get it? From where exactly can I download it? I could not find it.

Comment: Download a java SDK with sources and point your eclipse IDE to use it.

Comment: How do I point eclipse to use it? thanks.

Comment: Go to `Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`. Note that even after you do this, eclipse will still boot with whatever JRE's in your $PATH, it'll just use the newly downloaded SDK for all projects

Comment: in the installed jre it says: jre1.8.0_25. But there is nothing about jdk there. I still get "An exception occurred while getting the Javadoc". should I restart the whole computer?

Comment: I have there just an updated jre not the jdk. and still get exception when try to use javadoc

Comment: The JRE doesn't necessarily include sources. While you CAN download and use them with your JRE, that requires quite a bit of manual setup. The JDK, on the other hand, includes both a JRE and source files, and doesn't need any extra configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can find **eclipse.ini** in your Eclipse instalation folder.

Open it with notepad / notepad++ / sublime etc. and add:

**-vm <"Java SDK Path">** (for example your path could be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\javaw.exe)

**With this you will set default JDK for your eclipse instalation**

---

Another way to do it. Click with the right mouse button over your project:

1. Package Explorer -> Configure Build Path
2. Libraries
3. Add Library -> JRE System Library
4. Change the JRE to JDK

---

Another way is to try opening the declaration of some util class (Ctrl + click over the class). In the window appeared you can click "Attach source.." button and you can choose the path to your JDK.

Comment: how do I "Change the JRE to JDK?" I didn't found there such an option. also with 'Attach source' I still get 'An exception occurred while getting the Javadoc'. Why did they made this so complicated...

Comment: Go to [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and download Java JDK not JRE... Install it and then use instalation path as JDK path like I wrote you at the answer.